# How to highlight specific dates in an excel calendar based on start and end date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, calendar

I am coordinating a large amount of production orders that are linked to thereown projects. In the worksheet that I am working on I have created a calendar which I have managed to highlight weekend days and holidays using conditional formatting. I now need to highlight specific dates in the same calendar based on the start date and end date of each order (one row for each production order in the calendar).

Below you can see how it is set up and how I want it to be. Picture nr 1 shows you how I want it to be and I want it to automatically update if I change either start or end date.

How I want it to be:
[image: Picture of how i want it to be]

Comment: What conditional formatting are you using and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: For weekend dates/days i'm using the =WEEKDAY formula and for the holidays i'm using the =COUNTIF (But in Norwegian) the excel i'm using is from office 16. So when people write =AND(D$1>=$B2,D$1<=$C2), this section $B2,D$1 will fail because it does not recognize the comma between B" and D1. It needs to be ; Semicolon for the formula to work apparently.

Comment: The formula presented in the answer worked!

Comment: If the formula in the answer worked then you should mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I'm 100% Norwegian, my vocabulary is regrettably limited to fewer than 10 words. Below is *minimally reproducible example* of what I think you're trying to do.

Highlight your date range (D2:P4) and then create the following conditional format rule:

```
=AND(D$1>=$B2,D$1<=$C2)
```

This formula determines if the above date is between your start and end date. Fill with your desired color.

You mentioned you have another formula to highlight holidays and weekends. Adjust the order in which your two formulas run so that you can achieve your desired color scheme. If you don't want the start/end to overrule the Weekend/Holiday color, then place your Weekend/Holiday rule first and select  the "stop if true" button.

Skol!

[image]

Comment: Takk, jeg prøvde dette, men vet ikke om jeg gjør noe feil. Jeg fikk ikke ønsket resultat når jeg kopierte formelen og implementerte mine egne celler i formelen. Får ikke lagt til bilde i kommentar, men resultatet ble at kun 05.mai ble farget men ikke resten av tidsperioden fra start til sluttdato. Jeg bruker =ANTALL.HVIS for helligdager og =UKEDAG for helger.  Det jeg ønsker er at dagene/datoene fra t.o.m start dato til t.o.m slutt dato blir farget, men at helger og helligdager ikke endrer farge om disse havner i den spesifikke tidsperioden.

Comment: I tried it one more time and it worked! Thank you! Do i need to implement this formula for each row or is it any other easier way to make it so that this formula workes for each row with diferent dates?

Comment: You would select that date range (such as columns D through P), or more specifically, range D2:P4. Just make sure the first cell you select (D2) is the first one you expect to have in your conditional rule. Then the formula will automatically work for ALL cells because you have correctly locked the references (ie, the $ sign is in the right place, which I have in the formula).